# How can i create a 2 player turn-based board game on a separate android device using unity?

Tags: unity

im trying to make a 2 player turn-based board game, i have already made the connection between 2 device. I used photon. They both connect but i don't know how to sync them both to the game. can any one help me? i hope my question is right.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking about synchronising the game state between the players? Is this a P2P architecture or do you have an authoritative server?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't used Photon so I can't help on that front. If you are only making an Android game (and thus, you don't need to go cross platform game play) then you should look at the [play-games-plugin-for-unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) which is put out by Google.

Comment: the link doesn't work

Comment: @patrick Sorry about that! I just fixed it.